# Mixcr batch processing

Tags: ngs

I have a folder with 150 pairs of fastq files from an illumina sequence run. I need to precess them with mixcr, how can I do this in Bash with a single command?

Comment: What is your command for processing a single pair of FASTQ files?

Comment: You can use a for loop.

Comment: Here's an example of the command line that I'm using to run Mixcr for a pair of samples:  mixcr analyze amplicon --s hs \--staring-material dna \--5-end v-primers \--3-end j-primers \--adapters no-adapters \--receptor-type trb \--only-productive /Documents/Data/Input/S1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz /Documents/Data/Input/S1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  

The S1_S1_ component of the file name changes with each sample to S2_S2_  S3_S3_  all the way to 75.  I'm having a little problem setting the $variable for the file name in the loop.

Comment: One solution I thought is to try to iterate through the two types of files (R1 and R2) with a FOR loop, but I can't figure out how to do this.  I don't think a nested loop will do the trick.

Comment: Create a text file with two columns, one for R1 and the other for R2. Loop through this file. Shell loops are not a good thing to begin with, and nested loops are almost never required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach this:

```
for READ1 in /Documents/Data/Input/*R1*
do
    READ2=${READ1/R1/R2}
    mixcr analyze amplicon --s hs \
        --starting-material dna \
        --5-end v-primers \
        --3-end j-primers \
        --adapters no-adapters \
        --receptor-type trb \
        --only-productive "$READ1" "$READ2"
done
```

Basically, loop over all the R1 FASTQ files in a directory, and calculate the R2 names as needed.

This is using BASH string manipulation, and assumes that substituting `R2` for `R1` will correctly calculate the R2 filename from R1. It also assumes that all the FASTQ files are in a single directory.

Comment: Thanks.  This is essentially the approach that I took.  My original problem actually was the result of trying to run a shell command that wasn't compatible with the Linux version of shell.  When I used $ batch instead of $ sh to initiate my script, all the recommendations worked. I should have started by providing the bit of information that I am working in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 to be exact).

Comment: Ah - OK. Yes, you may want to use `bash` rather than `sh` if possible. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) as described in our guides :

https://docs.milaboratories.com/mixcr/guides/generic-multiplex-bcr/#one-command-solution

Briefly:

```
ls /Documents/Data/Input/*_R1* | \
    parallel -j 4 \
    'mixcr analyze 
    …
    {} \
    {=s:R1:R2:=} \             
{=s:.*/:/Documents/Data/result/:;s:_R.*::=}'
```

That will take all fastq pairs from /Documents/Data/Input and put the result output files into /Documents/Data/result folder.